# Lodash find object in nexted array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, lodash

I am currently working on an assignment in which I have to use `Lodash` and find an object inside JSON array. Below is my `JSON` string

```
var options = {
  'axisSeries': [
    ["xText", "xValue"],
    ["yText", "yValue"]
  ]
}
```

Now using `Lodash` I want to find string in 2nd Index of each array of `axisSeries`.

So for example if I search `xValue`. it should return me object as it is available in 2nd Index of First Array. Same for `yValue`.

But it should not return object for `xText` and `yText` as both of them are not available in second index.

to do so I want to use `Lodash` for that. But I could not find any appropriate function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON should be like,

```
var options = {
   'axisSeries': [
        { 'xText': 'X Text', 'xValue': 10 },
        { 'yText': 'Y Text', 'yValue': 20 }
    ]
}
```

And in Lodash use [_.pluck()](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_pluckcollection-path) to get `xValue` like,

```
_.pluck(options.axisSeries, 'xValue');
// should return [10]
```

**Alternatively,** You can use [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map),

```
_.map(options.axisSeries, 'xValue');
```

If you want to get the whole array by `xValue` then you can use [_.filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) like,

```js
var options = {
  'axisSeries': [
    ["xText", "xValue"],
    ["yText", "yValue"]
  ]
}

console.log(
   _.filter(options.axisSeries, function(o) { return o.indexOf('xValue')!=-1; })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_.map` with `_.last`, or if you need to get a specific index you could use `_.nth`. Also you should tell your teacher about [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). it has a better structure and capability to compose functions.

```js
var options = {
  'axisSeries': [
    ["xText", "xValue"],
    ["yText", "yValue"]
  ]
}

console.log(
  _.map(options.axisSeries, _.last),
  _.map(options.axisSeries, xs => _.nth(xs, 1))
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You must not be using an es6 compatible browser. I have added babel compilation to the snippet. it should fix the issue.